# JPA Disable auto generation of DDL

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase

I am working on a project based (among other things) on Spring Boot, JPA/Hibernate and Liquibase.

When I start the application using the command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=default,test
```

everything works as expected: all the tables are created and the data is initialised by liquibase, a few integration tests that verify the ORM work correctly as well. I am able to add rows to the database, generate the primary keys as UUIDs in PostgreSQL, create relations between these resources, etc...

The problem happens only when I try to execute `mvn clean package` or `mvn -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=default,test clean package`. The build is successful. The integration tests are executed and they are successful as well, but during the build I can see some exception like the one below.

I am not so much interested in the error itself. I do not understand why hibernate is trying to execute a DDL when I specifically disabled that functionality.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)

2020-09-25 17:21:56.428  INFO 104363 --- [           main] c.c.c.repository.JpaRepositoryTests      : Starting JpaRepositoryTests on pcdrugo with PID 104363 (started by marco in /core/clause_library/clause-library-repository)
2020-09-25 17:21:56.432  INFO 104363 --- [           main] c.c.c.repository.JpaRepositoryTests      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-25 17:21:56.544  INFO 104363 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-09-25 17:21:56.630  INFO 104363 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 85ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-09-25 17:21:56.849  INFO 104363 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2020-09-25 17:21:56.878  INFO 104363 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2020-09-25 17:21:57.261  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET SEARCH_PATH TO public
2020-09-25 17:21:57.262  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock
2020-09-25 17:21:57.267  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock
2020-09-25 17:21:57.271  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
2020-09-25 17:21:57.278  INFO 104363 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully acquired change log lock
2020-09-25 17:21:57.279  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET SEARCH_PATH TO public
2020-09-25 17:21:57.390  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT MD5SUM FROM public.databasechangelog WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
2020-09-25 17:21:57.392  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangelog
2020-09-25 17:21:57.393  INFO 104363 --- [           main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Reading from public.databasechangelog
2020-09-25 17:21:57.393  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT * FROM public.databasechangelog ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2020-09-25 17:21:57.399  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET SEARCH_PATH TO public
2020-09-25 17:21:57.422  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET SEARCH_PATH TO public
2020-09-25 17:21:57.426  INFO 104363 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully released change log lock
2020-09-25 17:21:57.426  INFO 104363 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SET SEARCH_PATH TO public
2020-09-25 17:21:57.450  INFO 104363 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-09-25 17:21:57.524  INFO 104363 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2020-09-25 17:21:58.016  WARN 104363 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table if exists clause add constraint FK9yf1oqlc0nt2mg20okv53kfmm foreign key (fk_source_clause_relation_clause_id) references clause" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists clause add constraint FK9yf1oqlc0nt2mg20okv53kfmm foreign key (fk_source_clause_relation_clause_id) references clause" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) ~[spring-test-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: there is no primary key for referenced table "clause"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    ... 99 common frames omitted
```

In my application.yaml I have added:

```
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    generate-ddl: false
```

It seems to me that this configuration is ignored.

The error is not thrown if I disable the tests:

```
mvn -DskipTests clean package
```

Comment: Is your file named `application.yaml` or `application.yml`?

Comment: it is called application.yaml

Comment: Rename it to `application.yml`.

Comment: Same behaviour with the other name. As I mentioned, the application works and so the yaml file is read.

Comment: I had this problem with `@ForeignKey`, `@UniqueConstraint` annotations. Try to remove them if you have and perform same operations.

Comment: @Ghokun I should probably make more clear that the problem I have is not the error itself, but the fact that hibernate is trying to create the tables. I am using Liquibase to initialise them.

Comment: Have you tried setting these properties in `src/test/resources/application.yml`

Comment: @Ghokun Same error.  I have fixed the issue with the primary key and now it does not show any error, but this does not mean that hibernate stopped trying to execute DDLs.